# lxml XPath position() does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath

I tried to scrape a page via XPath but I could not get it work as expected.

The page is like,

```
<tag1>
    <tag2>
          ....
              <div id=article>
                  <p> stuff1 </p>
                  <p> stuff2 </p>
                  <p> ...... </p>
                  <p> stuff30 </p>
```

I want to extract `stuff1` through `stuff30` as string. Here is my Python code snippet.

```
import lxml.html
import urllib.request

html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.something.com/news/blah/').read()
root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

content = root.xpath('string(//div[@id="article"]/p[position()=>1 and position()<=last()]/.)')
```

This code did not return anything.

If I rewrite from `position()` statement to individual element index, it works.

```
content = root.xpath('string(//div[@id="article"]/p[25]/.)')
```

This code returns `stuff25` correctly.

I don't want to run for loop just for this. I believe there is a way to get my code work with `position()`, but not sure what's wrong in my code.

Comment: Is that correct near the `position()=>1`? Shouldn't that be `position() >= 1`?

Comment: No, it appears it does not work... Per @tomalak comment below, string in XPath does not work with multiple nodes.

Comment: @K.K. It should be `>=` nonetheless. `=>` will cause an error.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you have position()=>1, should be position()>=1

```
content = root.xpath('string(//div[@id="article"]/p[position()>=1 and position()<=last()]/.)')
```

will set content to stuff1.

Comment: Additional note for the OP: `string(//multiple/nodes)` will give you the string representation of the first node only (compare [the documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string)). Don't try to convert to string in XPath, do it in the host language if you want to work with multiple nodes.