# lxml XPath - extracting text from multi p nodes

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, lxml

### Please have a look at [lxml XPath position() does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242154/lxml-xpath-position-does-not-work) first.

Since XPath does not support to extract text from multi nodes, I decided to write for loop to get 30 stuffs.

```
for i in range(1,31):
    content = "string(//div[@id='article']/p[" + (print(i)) + "]/.)"
    print(content)
```

I imagined it would return like,

```
"string(//div[@id='article']/p[1]/.)"
"string(//div[@id='article']/p[2]/.)"
"string(//div[@id='article']/p[3]/.)"
....
"string(//div[@id='article']/p[30]/.)"
```

However, obviously it does not work as I expected.. I got error message as following.

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

What should I do? Any other elegant approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python3, `print` is a *function* which prints to the screen *and returns* `None`. (In Python2, `print` is a *statement* and the code would have raised an error since you can't put a statement in the middle of an expression.) Instead, to build a string use the `format` method:

```
content = "string(//div[@id='article']/p[{}]/.)".format(i)
```

---

And by the way, you should be able to use `position()` just fine with lxml. For instance,

```
import lxml.html as LH
content = '''\
    <bookstore>
      <book>
        <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
        <price>29.99</price>
      </book>
      <book>
        <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
        <price>39.95</price>
      </book>
      <book>
        <title lang="eng">Things Fall Apart</title>
        <price>19.99</price>
      </book>
      <book>
        <title lang="eng">Blood Meridian</title>
        <price>9.99</price>
      </book>
    </bookstore>'''
root = LH.fromstring(content)

# Compare with https://stackoverflow.com/a/39242701/190597
print(root.xpath('//book[position()>=1 and position()<=last()]/title/text()'))
# ['Harry Potter', 'Learning XML', 'Things Fall Apart', 'Blood Meridian']

# But note that it is equivalent to 
print(root.xpath('//book/title/text()'))
# ['Harry Potter', 'Learning XML', 'Things Fall Apart', 'Blood Meridian']

print(root.xpath('//book[position()<3]'))
```

prints

```
['Harry Potter', 'Learning XML']
```

which shows that you can select the first `N` `books` without having to loop.

---

[As Tomalak mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242154/lxml-xpath-position-does-not-work#comment65822655_39242701), the XPath `string` function only returns the string representation of the first node. For example,

```
print(root.xpath('string(//book[position()<3]/title/text())'))
```

only prints

```
Harry Potter
```

If you want a list of strings, then don't use `string`.

If, as [Daniel Haley points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256973/lxml-xpath-extracting-text-from-multi-p-nodes/39257015?noredirect=1#comment65851036_39257015), the desired text is in a mixture of nested nodes and child elements, e.g. `<title lang="eng">Harry <b>Potter</b></title>`, then you can extract the desired text using the `text_content` method:

```
[title.text_content() for title in root.xpath('//book[position()<3]/title')]
```

Comment: One good reason to use `string()` is when `title` has mixed content (both text nodes and child elements) and you want the full string value. For example given `<title lang="eng">Harry <b>Potter</b></title>` you still want `Harry Potter` returned.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt follow up! It worked!

Answer (score 1):

The trailing `/.` in your xpath is invalid.

Try:

```
content = "string(//div[@id='article']/p[" + (print(i)) + "])"
```

Full example:

```py
import lxml.html

html = """<tag1>
<tag2>
<div id="article">
<p> stuff1 </p>
<p> stuff2 </p>
<p> stuff30 <b>more stuff</b></p>
</div>
</tag2>
</tag1>"""

root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

for i in range(1,4):
    content = root.xpath("string(//div[@id='article']/p[" + str(i) + "])")
    print(content)
    #stuff1
    #stuff2
    #stuff30 more stuff
```